# How to find curved line in image?

Tags: image-processing, sorting, clustering

What's the best way to find smooth curves in an image? I can use EdgeDetect[] to generate a binary image with what looks to my human eye like two distinct smooth curves, and I can get the coordinates of all of the nonzero elements of the array that make up the lists. But I can't figure out how to sort them into two ordered lists. Ideally, I'd also like a smooth fit function like an interpolation object that approximately went through the points and that I could manipulate mathematically (taking derivatives and such).

FindShortestTour[] seems like it would be useful, but I need to divide up the two curves first. FindClusters[] is not doing the trick because the curves are concentric, so even though they never pass too close to one another I can't get Mathematica to see that they form two distinct groups.

Comment: Please include your image and the code you've tried so far.